# how to get a data from another data in python json

Tags: python, json

This is the response I get from the server:

```
[{"status": "OK", "data":[{"Number":"9358925074","Name":"mark","Family":"tomson"}]}]
```

and if I want to get the `Name` value from the response, what can I do? can someone make a example in python?

Comment: Check the [documentation of python's json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: assuming `L` is the variable assigned to the response, I would say something like `L[0]['data'][0]['Number']` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
data = json.loads(j.content.decode())
for d in data:
    pass
name = (d['data'][0]['Number'])
print(name)
```

output:

```
9358925074
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```py
>>> data = [{"status": "OK", "data":[{"Number":"9358925074","Name":"mark","Family":"tomson"}]}]
>>> data[0]['data'][0]['Name']
'mark'
```

output:
`'mark'`